# How to copy path of a file in emacs helm-mode

Tags: emacs, copy-paste, emacs-helm

I'm using helm-mode in emacs to open files. However, when I try to copy the path of a file (say /home/user1/Documents/file1.txt) through mouse left-click and hold to paste it in terminal, I get a message saying

`<down-mouse-1> is undefined`

I guess helm does not support mouse operations as described [here](http://%20github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/501#issuecomment-140496283.), in which case how can I copy path of a file from emacs (in helm-mode) to paste it in terminal

Answer (score 5):

The answer given [in this other thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19834) may seem more straightforward.

In short: with the file selected in the minibuffer use `C-u C-c C-k`. This invokes `helm-kill-selection-and-quit`. The file's full path is copied to the kill ring and can be pasted in Emacs or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to copy from Minibuffer to your system clipboard. Minibuffer keybinding isn't different from other buffers. If in other buffers you use `M-w` to copy the region, it should also work in Minibuffer. Note that if you `nil`ed `x-select-enable-clipboard` you need to enable it first. I have the following functions in my `init.el`

```
(defun copy-to-clipboard()
  (interactive)
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
  (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil))
```

and

```
(defun paste-from-clipboard ()
  (interactive)
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
  (yank)
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil))
```

Unfortunately you can't use your mouse to select the texts (ie. to make a region) in helm-mode; you need to `set-mark-command` (by default `C-SPC` or `C-@`) and move your point (ie. cursor). Or just hold the `shift` and move the point like most other text editors. There is also a `mark-word` command (by default `M-@`) that expands the region word by word.

I also recorded an `asciinema` (because they're fun ) that you can watch it [here](https://asciinema.org/a/c66ssnjh7w2gmnz8kr7msesjf)